# Resolve forces using trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

3. Two tugs are towing a barge. One tug is steaming at a bearing of 102° with a force of 50 Kilonewtons (KN). The other is steaming at a bearing of 151G° with a force of 91 KN. Find the resultant force on the barge (to the nearest KN), and its direction (to the nearest degree).

[This is how i've attempted to to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYEzF.jpg) but i've been told its incorrect and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You conclude that angle $C$ is $135$ degrees because you get an angle
of $22.5$ degrees from somewhere (I have no idea where),
you draw a figure in which the $22.5$ degree angle is one of the two
other angles of a triangle with angle $C,$ and then you apparently
assume the triangle is isosceles (which is clearly *not* true, since
you have labeled the two supposedly equal sides with forces of
different magnitudes, which should correspond to the lengths of those sides).

There is a much simpler way to get the angle between the two forces.
One side of your parallelogram makes an angle $102$ degrees from your
reference line, the other makes an angle $151$ degrees from the reference.
So the first side splits the second angle into two parts,
one of $102$ degrees, the other $151 - 102 = 49$ degrees.
That's one angle of your parallelogram.
Angle $C$ is the adjacent angle, so it's $180 - 49 = 131$ degrees.

But I would recommend instead that you resolve  each of the two tugs'
forces into $x$ and $y$ components, add them componentwise,
and use the Pythagorean Theorem and an arc tangent to get the magnitude
and direction of the total force.
I find this more straightforward and less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding answer has been very helpful.